# error: argument of type ‘void* (Thread::)(void*)’ does not match ‘void* (*)(void*)’

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm doing to implement thread class for my own using `pthread`. So, I create `Thread` class as below :

```
class Thread
{
public:
  Thread()
  {
  }

  virtual void* run(void *params) = 0;

  void start(void *params)
  {
    pthread_create (&threadId, 0, run, params);
    pthread_join (threadId, 0);
  }

private:
  pthread_t threadId;
};
```

After implementing this class and override `virtual run` function, I do compile this project. But `error: argument of type ‘void* (Thread::)(void*)’ does not match ‘void* (*)(void*)’` occurs. What is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Function pointers and member function pointers are not the same thing.

Comment: @chris: So, what should i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pthread_create` is a C function, and knows nothing of C++ member functions. You'll need to give it a static or non-member function, and pass a pointer to your `Thread` object via the final argument of `pthread_create`; something like:

```
class Thread
{
    virtual void* run(void *params) = 0;

    void start(void * params)
    {
        this->params = params;
        pthread_create(&threadId, 0, &Thread::static_run, this);
    }

    static void * static_run(void * void_this)
    {
         Thread * thread_this = static_cast<Thread*>(void_this);
         return thread_this->run(thread_this->params);
    }

private:
    pthread_t threadId;
    void *params;
};
```

Of course in modern C++, this is rather more straightforward:

```
std::thread thread;

void start(void * params)
{
    thread = std::thread([this]{run(params);});
}
```

(Although of course you shouldn't be using `void*` to pass your parameters, and there's probably no good reason to wrap the thread up in a class in the first place.)

Comment: But it has an error : `invalid use of member ‘Thread::params’ in static member function`

Comment: @HosseinMobasher: So it does; you'll need to use the function parameter to access that. Just a moment while I fix it...

Comment: @HosseinMobasher: It should be more correct now. Sorry, I don't have a compiler available and it's been years since I've had to cobble together my own threading primitives, so there might still be mistakes. You really should be looking at C++11 or Boost.Thread, rather than messing around with this nonsense.

Comment: Another error : `error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(void*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @HosseinMobasher: Sorry, I forgot about the `void*` return type for a pthread entry function. Try now. (Still no guarantee that I've got it right; as I say, I don't have a compiler and I don't usually rewrite basic library functionality).

Comment: @MikeSeymour, In case you're interested, the Coliru one has pthread support. Using Wikipedia's first example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ff7177952824fe02f7d4c2ae31880c1b-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what the compiler is telling you.

pthread_create is expecting a function with the signature :

`void* (*)(void*)`

Which is a function pointer.

However, you are providing something with this signature:

`void* (Thread::)(void*)`

Which is *not* a function pointer, but a pointer to member function. There is a difference : a pointer to member function needs an instance of an object in order to work properly (here, it would need an instance of Thread).

A usual solution would be to make your function `run` `static` : it would not be a member function anymore - it doesn't NEED an instance of Thread in order to work properly anymore, and you could pass your current instance as the last parameter of `pthread_create` in order to act on it once the thread is launched.
You would just need to save the parameters in the class itself.

```
public:
 void start(void *params)
 {
  this->my_thread_params = params;
  pthread_create (&threadId, 0, run, static_cast<void*>(this));
 }

private:
  static void *run(void *my_object)
  {
    // here, my_object already contains the params you passed to the function start
    static_cast<Thread*>(my_object)->my_member_function();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that a pointer to a member function in `Thread` that takes and returns a `void*` (`void* (Thread::*)(void*)`) is not convertible to a pointer to function taking and returning the same `void*`.

While the declaration of the member function may look similar to the type that you need, there is an implicit `this` pointer of type `Thread` that needs to be injected on any call to `Thread::run`